# bash: ./run: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, bash, permissions

The source code of the GOLIATH simulator and installation guide are provided in public.
[https://github.com/necst/GOLIATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiP6p.png)

However, I found it hard to install it. I got permission denied error as attached in the image file. I would be grateful for your suggestion. I have the following issues.

1. I make the omnet++ simulator in Ubuntu 20.04 and run the sumo server. It is showing running on port 9999. However, while I ran the run script, I got `bash: ./run: Permission denied error`:

[image: sumo]

[image: ./run error]

2. Do I need to install veins separately? or I can import from the downloaded GitHub repository? I have followed the second step.
3. Do I need to install INET separately?
4. `./run -c MoST-MaliciousRandom -u Cmdenv` (this example file is not present inside the simulator folder)

I would be grateful if you could provide the detailed steps for simulating in your simulator.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format them

Comment: Just to check the basics, is the `run` file actually executable?